# How to execute typescript angular function without (click) button in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to execute function when page opens.
I have typescript code:

```
export class MyReservationsPage implements OnInit {
  user: any;
  userId: string;
  storedData: any = [];

  constructor(private auth: AuthService, private afs: AngularFirestore) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fetchBookings();
  }

  fetchBookings() {
    this.afs
      .collection('user')
      .doc(this.userId)
      .collection('BookingHistory')
      .get()
      .subscribe((querySnapshot) => {
        this.storedData = querySnapshot.docs.map((e) => {
          return {
            bookingDate: e.data()['Merge'],
          };
        });
      });
  }
}
```

and HTML:

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-grid>
        <row *ngFor="let data of storedData">
            <ion-col *ngFor="let value of data.bookingDate">
                <ion-row>{{value.Date}}</ion-row>
                <ion-row>{{value.Time}}</ion-row>
                <ion-row>{{value.BookedAt.toDate() | date:'medium'}}</ion-row>
            </ion-col>
        </row>
    </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

I don't really know how `ngOnInit` works but How I can execute function automatically without clicking on button?

Comment: Just call it in the controller?

Comment: You can try afterviewinit

Comment: Sorry, but how to do that?

Comment: put code `ngOnInit(){this.fetchBookings()}` inside of your component. this hook `ngOnInit` is called on component initialization

Comment: still no result :(

Comment: Your components implemets from oninit or afterviewinit??

Comment: Please share your component code

Comment: `fetchBookings` is not getting called? where is `this.userId` set? any errors in the console?

Comment: What has changed since this question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/69879175/6294072 You have accepted answer, so assumingly it works/worked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ngOnInit` doesn't fire every time:

> A callback method that is invoked immediately after the default change detector has checked the directive's data-bound properties for the first time, and before any of the view or content children have been checked. It is invoked only once when the directive is instantiated.

Source: [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit)

If you want to call the function every time the view loads, you'd be better off using the Ionic lifecycle events detailed [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle).

So in your case, you could use something like:

```
export class MyReservationsPage {
  user: any;
  userId: string;
  storedData: any = [];

  constructor(
    private auth: AuthService,
    private afs: AngularFirestore
  ) {}

  ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.fetchbookings();
  }

  fetchBookings() {
    this.afs
      .collection('user')
      .doc(this.userId)
      .collection('BookingHistory')
      .get()
      .subscribe((querySnapshot) => {
        this.storedData = querySnapshot.docs.map((e) => {
          return {
            bookingDate: e.data()['Merge'],
          };
        });
      });
  }
}
```

That will call your `fetchBookings()` method after the view has loaded.